# SCONS PDB unable to find my file, even after I explicitly append it to the system path

Tags: python, debugging, scons, pdb

I'm trying to debug a scons file as follows: `scons --debug=pdb`. When I try to set a breakpoint in `SConstruct` using `b SConstruct:24` I get an error:

> *** 'SConstruct' not found from sys.path

My SConstruct file is in the current directory. I tried to append the current directory to `sys.path`. using `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` and then rerunning the `b SConstruct:24` command but I still get the same error. Any idea why this might occur?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the implementation of Python's pdb. On startup, the path of the script is inserted to `sys.path` - but that's SCons's path, not the path to your project. You can add that yourself to `sys.path` but it's not clear that actually works for `SConstruct`/`SConscript`: a docstring suggests that the `.py` can be omitted but that appears to mean if the file is named `something.py` you can ask for `something` - it adds `.py` when doing the lookup if the name you gave had no extension.  What does work is an absolute path to the `SConstruct`, because pdb's `lookupmodule` method starts with this:

```py
        if os.path.isabs(filename) and  os.path.exists(filename):
            return filename
```

That's admittedly a pain to need to type.

SCons does allow you to name your sconstruct file as `SConstruct.py`, which might help as a temporary measure while debugging this way.

Comment: as an updated, there's a proposed tweak which will recognize files named `SConstruct` and `SConscript` in the debugger opened this way, without them having to have a `.py` suffix (not accepted into the project as of the date of this comment)